# How to use the GrabResolver to use a remote repo in groovysh

Tags: groovy, groovy-grape

I know that you can use `@GrabResolver(name='restlet', root='http://maven.restlet.org/')` at the start of a groovy file. However, I wish to be able to do this call whilst I am in the groovysh.

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
groovy:000> import groovy.grape.Grape
===> [import groovy.grape.Grape]
groovy:000> Grape.addResolver(name:'restlet', root:'http://maven.restlet.org/')
===> null
```

`@GrabResolver` internally adds the above call (`Grape.addResolver()`) in the class where the annotation is used. By default this behaviour is driven by the `initClass` property being set to true in the annotation.